# How to access classes from different playground pages in playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm currently working on a single view playground. At this point, my main playground file has a bunch of view controller classes and is really disorganized. Im trying to reorganize my code by splitting up the view controller classes into separate playground files like how you would with a project.

I created a new playground file and transferred the code but the classes aren't recognized in the main playground file. I've also tried creating new swift files under sources, but the files don't allow for importing UIKit. I've also tried declaring the classes as public, but still no dice.

How can I access the code from different playground files? I've been unable to find any info regarding this.

I apologize if this question has been asked before, or the answer is obvious as I don't use playgrounds very often.

Comment: Having the files in "Sources" is the right solution. Just make sure that everything you need to access is declared as "public". Classes, methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

We can access the class by from source swift file by adding static and make function public

```
public class Person1 {
    public static func performTask() {
        print("Accessing Class")
    }
}
```